# Google Drive API Sharing permissions

Tags: python, permissions, google-drive-api

i have written a code where i will create google drive folder and share that via Email.

My idea is that my added users can add, edit files and etc, but they should not have access to share them, or add new users. I found how to do it manually, just put a tick in the advanced section, Screenshot for example:

[image]

but I cant find out how i can prevent editors from changing access and adding new people with python function code. I rummaged through the entire library, but I did not find the answer, maybe it impossible?

Answer (score 0):

Check this documentation about [Permissions](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-permissions) to get you started.

Here how it works,

> Lists of permissions are available for each file and folder in Drive.
>   Each permission specifies a [type](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions#resource), [role](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions#resource), and [emailAddress or domain](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions#resource),
>   permitting a level of access to a file or folder. These values work
>   together to limit the access appropriately. The type limits access to
>   a set of users. The email address and domain fields specify which
>   users can have access. Finally, the role gives these users the ability
>   to do something to the file, like read it. When combined, these
>   properties define a complete permission.

You can also visit this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-files) to get an insight about the basics of files and folders.

Comment: I know it , i have a working code , but i need just to prevent user from sharing !

Comment: Then i set type: reader , he is not allow do anything include sharing , just read.. and then i set writer type , he can read, edit, write and etc , sharing for him is possable to.. i just need to turn off for him sharing menu.